# How to remove woocommerce added cart items and redirect to checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce form to 'Add Funds'. It has an amount input field ($20, $30 ...etc.) and a submit button that redirects to cart page with the input amount as total.

Redirect to checkout is working, but the cart items are not getting removed if a user abandons the cart and tries to order again.

I tried numerous solutions for the redirect to checkout, but only one worked.

**Working solution for redirect to checkout:**

[WooCommerce - Skip cart page redirecting to checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655722/woocommerce-skip-cart-page-redirecting-to-checkout-page)

**Solutions not working for redirect to checkout:**

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267071/redirect-to-woocommerce-checkout-after-adding-to-cart-item-already-in-cart

[Woocommerce add to cart button redirect to checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592633/woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-redirect-to-checkout)

> N.B. I have added the working and not working solutions for redirect
>   to checkout because it may provide an insight as to why the empty cart
>   solutions are not working.

Incase of emptying cart before adding a new product, none of the solutions are working:

https://gist.github.com/viniciusrtf/b49403b5f87dcd7699c1

https://hungred.com/how-to/empty-woocommerce-cart-adding-item/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267071/redirect-to-woocommerce-checkout-after-adding-to-cart-item-already-in-cart

**Using Woocommerce 3.2.6 and WordPress 4.9.2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First you will need in WooCommerce Settings > Products > Display in "Add to cart behaviour" to enabled the checkbox : **Redirect to the cart page after successful addition**

Then you will need the 3 following hooked function:

1) Empty cart before add-to-cart (if cart is not empty)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'one_cart_item_at_the_time', 10, 3 );
function one_cart_item_at_the_time( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty())
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return $passed;
}
```

2) Add-to-cart redirection to checkout:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'add_to_cart_checkout_redirection', 10, 1 );
function add_to_cart_checkout_redirection( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}
```

3) Skip cart page redirecting to checkout:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout');
function skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout() {
    if( is_cart() )
        wp_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works *(with Woocommerce 3.2.6 and WordPress 4.9.2 on Storefront theme)*.

Comment: The cart is not getting emptied before add new items, and giving the error 'You cannot add another "Product" to your cart'. I was wondering if we can use the clear cart session function. I am a novice with php.   `function wc_empty_cart() {
 if ( ! isset( WC()->cart ) || '' === WC()->cart ) {
  WC()->cart = new WC_Cart();
 }
 WC()->cart->empty_cart( false );
}`

Comment: @mesumosu I don't get any error. I have tested the code in all possible ways. So you should try to remove before, other related customization code. This issue can also come from your theme or maybe from a plugin.

Comment: Thank u very much!!! You saved me hours of frustation by pointing me out to the plugin angle. I was using a free Woocommerce wallet plugin that was reassigning the `$product_id` to something different. Used the new assigned variable in place of `$product_id` and your solution for empty cart ( Code 1) worked. So, its been a lesson to learn, that when using woocommerce plugins, we have to check for the variables `$product_id` and `$cart_item_key` in the plugin. Well, what can I say, you are an amazing support!!!!

Comment: thank you. doesnt work on woocommerce 4+ can you update codes for woocomerce 4 and wordpress 5?