# How to skip checkout page Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tell me pls how to skip checkout page Woocommerce?

A [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvqNu.png) where a person simply has to click the "place order" button, since the rest of the data is substituted itself.
After clicking it is redirected to the payment gateway...

How do I skip this formality by clicking one button and redirect them straight to the payment gateway?

Comment: There is this answer I have used myself in the past. It redirects to the cart and removes the products from the user's cart so if they abandon it and come back there are no duplication of products in the cart. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502472/how-to-remove-woocommerce-added-cart-items-and-redirect-to-checkout

Answer (score 1):

Payment gateways is part of the WooCommerce checkout page. Do you have any payment gateways set up? May be you are referring to skipping the cart page and going to the checkout. Here's a great tutorial to do that: https://www.webroomtech.com/woocommerce-skip-cart-and-go-to-checkout/

```
    add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'webroom_redirect_add_to_cart');
function webroom_redirect_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cw_redirect_url_checkout = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $cw_redirect_url_checkout;
}
```

add the above code to functions.php file and save it. From now on every time a user clicks the add-to-cart button it will be redirected to the checkout page.

Comment: in the booking plugin, my customer enters the date and time and his contacts -> Click Next and it will be redirected to the woocomerce payment page (yes I already missed the cart page), where you usually enter the shipping address that I do not need. -> Click on "Place Order" -> it will be redirected to the external page of the bank (card data entry page).

How do I skip this step by entering the delivery address and clicking on "place order".

P.S. Plug-in works with woocommerce, payment gateway works with woocommerce too - so it is obligatory link.

I will be glad to receive any help