# Woocommerce avoid checkout and finish the order in cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I'm searching without lucky, how to finish the order process in Cart Page without go to the checkout page, Im using Woocommerce for internal use and I don't need any payment method neither billing info and so on.

Anyone know if there any way to avoid the checkout process and finish the order in the cart page?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce - Skip cart page redirecting to checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655722/woocommerce-skip-cart-page-redirecting-to-checkout-page)

Comment: it's the opposite, I need avoid the checkout and finish the process in Cart Page.

Thanks anyway!